# How to update part of a displayed view in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, internet-explorer-6

I have a view which calls a partial view using:

```
Html.RenderPartial
```

I'd like to call this in isolation using a controller method to stop the whole page having to be refreshed but controller methods returning void seem to destroy the existing view (I get a blank screen).

I have the javascript code to update the HTML document section but I can't see how to retain the view/get a reference to it in the controller to call the javascript method.

I should add that I'm fairly new to this MVC3 thing.

N.B. to cut a long story short, using JQuery is not an option so we're limited to Javascript unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic pattern is to create a PartialView result in the Controller and use that result to update the innerHTML of some container on your page:

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" onclick="UpdateMyContainer();" value="Update" />

<div id="MyContainer">
    @Html.Partial( "_MyPartialView", Model )
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

Follow [Ajax without jQuery for beginners](http://blog.mgechev.com/2011/07/21/ajax-jquery-beginners/) for creating an Ajax method that doesn't require JQuery. Essentially:

```
function UpdateMyContainer() {
  var xmlHttp = createXMLHttp();
  // set your controller URL here:
  xmlHttp.open('get', 'Url/To/SomeMethodInController', true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4) {
      if (xmlHttp.status === 200) {
        // Set the Id of the container to update here:
        document.getElementById('MyContainer').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
      } else {
        alert('Error: ' + xmlHttp.responseText);
      }
    } else {
      //still loading
    }
  };
}
```

The above JS could be further refactored to take in a URL and an ID of an element to update.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult SomeMethodInController()
{
    var model = MethodToRetreiveModel();

    return PartialView( "_MyPartialView", model );
}
```

Comment: The partial refresh isn't fired by an element on the form - it would be by some other controller method. Would this be a problem?

Comment: The example isn't based on using form events; the JS submits the post to the controller which returns the partial view. I'm not sure I'm following: "some other controller method" would be invoked? Or? And How?

Comment: The updating of the partial view isn't triggered by a button press or anything on the view. It would be via some controller method which is fired by a barcode scan on the device. I guess what I'm asking is can I call a JavaScript function directly in the controller method.

Comment: OK, that's a bit different. What you're looking for are server-side events to update the client. One option is to implement [SignalR](http://signalr.net). And here's an article of hand-rolling an HTML5 server-side event: [Strem Updates with Server Side Events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) - it's in PHP, but the concepts are the same for MVC.

Comment: That sounds like it would be another framework to push down to the device which we're trying to avoid...

Comment: SignalR is pure JS on the client side. If you can use strict HTML 5, then look at the other article of Stream Updates with Server Side Events. There is no built in functionality in the MVC framework (AFAIK) that will push updates to the client from the server without some type of client interaction first.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a postscript, I finally got round to trying this on IE6 (don't ask!). Had to make some slight tweaks but otherwise it works a beauty!

```
var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHttp');
```

And

```
xmlHttp.open('post', 'Url/To/SomeMethodInController', true);
```